# Generating jaxb classes from a schema

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I am trying to use the Jaxb classes generator in eclipse to generate jaxb classes from my schema.
I receive the following error:

"The classpath for this project does not appear to contain the necessary libraries to proceed with class generation.
Please insure that a JAXB implementation is available on the classpath."

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What Java version are you using? How are you generating the classes (i.e. with ant's XJC task, on the console, etc)?

Comment: I am trying to use the eclipse JAXB class generation

Comment: Which version of Java? Jaxb is not shipped with version prior to 1.6.

Comment: @ErikSapir: Are you sure you have one one Java in your system? It may happen that Eclipse is running under one version of Java and your Eclipse Project is using another version of Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to include the `jaxb-impl.jar` library in your project. You can download one for example from here:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.4/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar

If you're using Maven, you can include this as a dependency, otherwise download the file and add it as a library in your project.

If you need a different version of the library, move up one directory in the link that I added above, you can find other versions there as well.

If you want to automate the class generation, since you're changing the schema on a regular basis, you should automate the process, e.g through Maven.

Answer (score 11):

After a lot of research here is what I have done to fix the issue.
Windows> Preferences> Java> InstalledJREs...make sure to point your jre to the jdk directory. I was pointing to JRE and as soon as I changed it to JDK, it started working.
Hope this will help you guys.

Comment: This is because the class generator uses XJC, which is shipped in the JDK  but not in the JRE.

Answer (score 3):

Windows> Preferences> Java> InstalledJREs > Execution Environment. Select an environment JDK 1.8 and then try to create JAXB Classes.

Click on Below Image Link For Details.

[Select the execution Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPYa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Put the tools.jar in the classpath of the projecct (where the generated code will reside).

I found an explanation here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345617
It does not work because Eclipse only puts the JRE libraries in the classpath of the project. Since the xjc code is in tools.jar you need to provide this extra step.

Answer (score 1):

[Download com.springsource.com.sun.tools.xjc-2.1.7.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourcecomsuntoolsxjc217jar.htm)

and configure the build path.
This solved the warning and the error for me. Hope this helps.